# store data with realm retrieved by backendless same as parse LocalStorage

Tags: android, backendless

hey guys i just switched from `parse` to `backendless` and

`backendless` didnt support local storage yet so i have do it by myself (store the retrieved data) i just want some guidance how am gonna do that ? do i need to store them with a hashmap array ? or i have to store different columns of data into different arrays ? i want to store them without making any mess (efficiently) what is the best way of doing this please guide me guys thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Android, the best way to do that is to use some [ORM frameworks](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-best-android-orms/). As an alternative I can suggest you fast nosql store:

https://github.com/FabianTerhorst/Iron

Anyway, Backendless is planning to introduce offline-mode so follow its blog [here](https://backendless.com/blog/).